# I cant access wordpress CMS after I installed a plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I installed a plugin in my wordpress site, and after I installed that every time I try to access the CMS it redirects me to http://mysite.com/wp-admin/install.php

How can I solve this, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the plugin is dodgy? If not, you probably have an issue with your permissions. We'd need a bit more information about what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Uninstall the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try deleting the plugin (via ftp) that caused the problem.

Comment: why not? you delete the plugin, you fix the problem... (i'm guessing that he doesn't have access to the admin either in order to uninstall it)

Comment: @RCV See? It was an answer, and it was an answer that worked for the OP.

Comment: glad to hear. happened to me once ;)